# Preprocessor Directives Reflection Injection

Tags: c#, reflection, preprocessor-directive

**How** to inject [`C# Preprocessor Directives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(v=vs.71).aspx) to an interface by Reflection ?

Example :
I want to inject `#if SILVERLIGHT` to any WCF service contract interface.

Comment: Preprocessor commands are evaluated prior to code generation.  They don't exist in assemblies to be reflected against.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.
Slightly longer answer: you question doesn't even make sense in the first place.

Preprocessor directives are processed before compilation. The result of that processing is the new, modified, source code. That source code then gets compiled.

For example, if the `SILVERLIGHT` symbol is not defined at the time of compilation, then the whole code between `#if SiLVERLIGHT` and `#endif` will be completely ignored by the compiler as if it wasn't even there.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. As per the name, preprocessor directives exist only just before compile time. Nowhere else.