# C# How to get a list of defined preprocessor?

Tags: c#, preprocessor-directive

I know I can check if a preprocessor directive is defined using the #if syntax.

But I want to get a list of defined preprocessor directives to pass it over to a realtime compiling using CSharpCodeProvider

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023791/preprocessor-directives-reflection-injection).

The compiler itself doesn't know about preprocessor. It receives already preprocessed code so there is no reason to remember what directives were defined.